# Seeking maximum parameter value so that inequality always holds true

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

What is the largest positive integer $n$ such that
$$\frac{a^2}{\frac{b}{29}+\frac{c}{31}} + \frac{b^2}{\frac{c}{29}+\frac{a}{31}} + \frac{c^2}{\frac{a}{29}+\frac{b}{31}} \;\ge\; n\,(a+b+c)$$
holds true for all positive real numbers $a,b,c\,$?

I tried using AM $\ge$ GM $\ge$ HM inequality on the numbers $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{a^2}\left(\frac{b}{29}+\frac{c}{31}\right)},
\frac{1}{\frac{1}{b^2}\left(\frac{c}{29}+\frac{a}{31}\right)},
\frac{1}{\frac{1}{c^2}\left(\frac{a}{29}+\frac{b}{31}\right)}$ since that seems like the only thing that comes to my mind when seeing a homogenous inequality, but that doesn't work at all.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Pls contribute more than just
"Here's my question & I'm clueless & Help is welcome." !
Why are you considering it?
What did you do/try to solve it?
As it stands, it's a pure PSQ.

Comment: Btw, the optimal parameter value is not integer ...

Comment: @Hanno please elaborate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AM $\geqslant$ HM is viable in its weighted form
$\,\sum_k w_kx_k\geqslant\big(\sum_k w_k\,x^{-1}_k\big)^{-1}\,$:
$$\frac a{a+b+c}\cdot\frac a{31b+29c}
+ \frac b{a+b+c}\cdot\frac b{31c+29a}
+ \frac c{a+b+c}\cdot\frac c{31a+29b}\\[3ex]
\geqslant \left(\frac a{a+b+c}\cdot\frac {31b+29c}a
+ \frac b{a+b+c}\cdot\frac{31c+29a}b
+ \frac c{a+b+c}\cdot\frac{31a+29b}c\right)^{-1}
= \frac 1 {60}$$
Hence the optimal parameter is $\frac{29\cdot 31}{60}\lessapprox 15$, therefore the largest positive integer is $\,n=14\,$.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution relies on the [Cauchy-Bunyakowski-Schwarz inequality in the form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sedrakyan%27s_inequality)
$$\begin{align}
\sum_k\frac{x_k^2}{y_k} & \;\geqslant\;\frac{\left(\sum_k x_k\right)^2}{\sum_k y_k}\\[1.67ex]
\implies\;\frac{a^2}{31b+29c} + \frac{b^2}{31c +29a} + \frac{c^2}{31a +29b}  & \;\geqslant\; \frac{(a+b+c)^2}{31b+29c + 31c+29a + 31a +29b}\\[1.5ex]
& \;=\;\frac1 {60}\,(a+b+c)\end{align}$$